# wordpress widget overlaying text

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website and the new widget is over the old text. I need to take all my next and convert it somehow to take up less space so that the text doesn't overlay under the widget.

Comment: Atleast post your markup here..

Comment: One thing I have seriously noticed is that Stackoverflow people always need an example.

Comment: we are not superheros with some kinda super powers who can fix a code without knowing your code

Comment: make your content width to 50% and see...that's all

Comment: Yea, I have tried  using p style and body style. body style made a horrible problem because of the way wordpress is made. and the p style failed, didn't do anything. What exactly are you talking about? could you give me a code example? thank you very much

Comment: for testing purpose try including these styles in your `<p>` element which holds this text "Working with a realtor doing web design" like this `<p style="width: 300px;">`

Comment: Is there a way to use percent instead of pixels?

Comment: Good job, it partially worked. The first paragraph is 300 pixels wide. The rest of it is not however. I wonder if a <p> was ended somewhere

Comment: It only works every paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See I was saying something like this :

Give width's to your `<p>` elements

[**My fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aTm2d/1/)

or wrap all paragraph's in a `<div>`

[**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aTm2d/2/) (Wrapped In a `<div>`)

Comment: Was going to tell u 2 make an answer so i can 1up it

Comment: hey mr alien. I notice your always there to save the day